# htaccess redirect not working as thought

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Ok so i have an admin folder in a site that i am working and what i need is when someone enters

```
http://admin.teamfocususa.org/
```

in their browser then they get redirected to the admin folder

here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teamfocususa.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.teamfocususa.org$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/admin/(.*)$ http://admin.teamfocususa.org/$1

Redirect http://admin.teamfocususa.org /admin
```

this part is not working

```
Redirect http://admin.teamfocususa.org /admin
```

any ideas on how to make this part work ...when i visit `http://admin.teamfocususa.org` is the home page and not the admin folder as i thought....FYI this is a shared host and I dont have access to the vhost to fix this the way i know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `RewriteRule` matching on requests to `/` of `admin.teamfocususa.org`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teamfocususa\.org^ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.teamfocususa.org$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?teamfocususa\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) http://admin.teamfocususa.org/$1 [L,R=301]

# Not needed
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/admin/(.*)$ http://admin.teamfocususa.org/$1

# Added = requests to http://admin.teamfocususa.org/
# Redirected into http://admin.teamfocususa.org/admin
# --OOPS fixed RewriteCond - was typo RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.teamfocususa\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ admin/ [L,R=301]

# To hide /admin on admin.teamfocususa.org
# use this instead of the above group...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.teamfocususa\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ admin/ [L]


# Not needed
#Redirect http://admin.teamfocususa.org /admin
```

Comment: @micheal - they both dont work now...i put your entire htaccess in the root directory

Comment: I need teamfocususa.org to use the index.php and root directory and when someone enters admin.teamfocususa.org i need the admin/index.php

Comment: @Tamer See changes above.  I removed the other RedirectMatch and replaced it with a RewriteRule  to do the redirection from either the www or non-www domain to admin. That should also take care of the other one not working. The whole thing should be at the site root.

Comment: all is good other then the main site at teamfocususa.org should not redirect to admin and it does

Comment: @Tamer You mean `teamfocususa.org/admin` redirects to `admin.teamfocususa.org` and shouldn't, or `teamfocususa.org/` redirects to `admin.teamfocususa.org`?

Comment: if you visit teamfocususa.org/ it should not redirect but it does for some reason ..

Comment: teamfocususa.org/admin does redirect to admin.teamfocususa.org as it should ....this works correct

Comment: @Tamer but specifically what is it redirecting to ? admin.teamfocususa.org the domain or /admin the directory?

Comment: Oh wait, I see it!  A typo above. There was a `RewriteRule` where there should have been a `RewriteCond`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8949/discussion-between-tamer-and-michael)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you want to do a Redirect, but a simple RewriteRule to show the admin folder for the domain admin.teamfocususa.org

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If not admin.teamfocususa.org and in /admin folder, redirect to admin.teamfocususa.or
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.teamfocususa.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$ http://admin.teamfocususa.org/$1 [L,R=301]

# If domain is admin.teamfocususa.org, show files from admin folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin.teamfocususa.org [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /admin$1 [L]

# if domain is teamfocususa.org, redirect to www.teamfocususa.org
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teamfocususa.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.teamfocususa.org$1 [L,R=301]
```

UPDATE: My domain checks were wrong, try this updated version

Comment: when i enter admin.teamfocususa.org in the browser ...i get http://admin.teamfocususa.org/admin/ and 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: The domain check were incorrect, admin.teamfocususa.org was being redirect to admin.teamfocususa.org/admin and stopping the mod rewrite chain.